# which curent_date function will work for impala and trino?

Tags: hive, presto, impala, trino

```
trino - select cast(date_format(current_date,'Y%M%D') as int) from employee;
impala - select cast(from_timestamp(now(),'YYYMMDD') as int) from employee;
```

Is any function is available which works in both cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `current_date()` in impala. Its a func so you need to use ().
https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html#datetime_functions__current_date

Comment: As far as I understand OP wants to have the same SQL running both against  Presto and Impala so the query returns date as integer, how does `current_date` help?

Comment: `current_date()` and `now()` are same/similar (one without timestamp and other with). so not much help

Answer (score 0):

Trino and Impala both support now() and return a timestamp. However I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with the casting.